# $\cos\left(\frac pq x\right)$, $p\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb N$ to $f(\cos x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Is there a formula that relates $\cos\left(\frac pq x\right)$, $p\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb N$, to $\cos x$ ?

I thought of $\cos^2\left(\frac pq x\right)=\frac{1+\cos\left(\frac {2p}q x\right)}{2}$ and it doesn't leave here, only and only in case of $p=1$ and $q=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\cos(x) = c$, so $\sin(x) =  \pm\sqrt{1-c^2}$ and $\exp(\pm ix) = c \pm i \sqrt{1-c^2} $ (not necessarily with the same $+$ and $-$).  Then $\exp(\pm ipx/q) = (c \pm i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q}$ so
$$ \cos(px/q) = \frac{\exp(ipx/q) + \exp(-ipx/q)}{2} = \frac{ (c + i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q} + (c - i \sqrt{1-c^2})^{p/q}}{2}$$

Of course the multi-valued nature of the $p/q$ power of complex numbers must be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

In general? Not really. Computing rational multiples of a cosine, sine or tangent (etc.) is often doable in principle, and definitely easy - in principle - if you're just taking $\cos(px)$, but as soon as you take half, or third angles, you need to solve quadratic and cubic equations respectively. These expressions will quickly become complicated, and once you hit $q\ge5$ [it's no longer possible in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) to solve these quintic - or higher - equations in terms of radicals (i.e. "nicely").